# Create RDS free tier instance using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Looking at the docs here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

I dont see a way to specify that I want to create an RDS instance within the free tier. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no flag or option to create any AWS resources "within the free tier". The free-tier is simply a list of resources you can use for free. You would create resources that conform to the free-tier restrictions, and they would show up as free on your monthly bill.

The AWS [Free Tier for RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/) currently states:

> - 750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro Instance usage running MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle BYOL or SQL Server (running SQL
>   Server Express Edition) – enough hours to run a DB Instance
>   continuously each month
> - 20 GB of General Purpose (SSD) DB Storage*
> - 20 GB of backup storage for your automated database backups and any user-initiated DB Snapshots*

So you would need to make sure you create a `db.t2.micro` instance, make sure you don't provision more than 20GB of General Purpose storage, and make sure you don't enable any other things like provisioned IO, or performance insights, to ensure that you are not charged.